# Is it a good practice to use static block to initialize a shared queue

Tags: java, static, initialization, singleton

I have a class A. Its main functions are to construct data and call an addToQueue(Data data) method in Class B. Class B is to construct a persistent queue and add data to the queue. In order to make sure Class A and Class B share the same queue. I use a static block in CLass B to initialize the persistent queue and also make Class B singleton. I am not sure it is the right way or not. Any better solution to do that?

Comment: If Class B's members are static, what's the point of making it a singleton?

Comment: @shmosel Class B also has some other methods to handle the data in the persistent queue.

Comment: If Class B is singleton then you might as well initialize the queue in the constructor of Class B rather than a static block. Also, what do you mean by Share a Queue? I'm assuming the Queue is within the boundaries of Class B and is not exposed outside.

Comment: @Bandi Kishore  What I am trying to do is when other classes call Class A, Class A will get Class B instance and call the addToQueue method. I wanna make sure that Class A always get the same Class B instance and the same persistent queue.